# How to test a network during training in tensorflow when using a queue

Tags: queue, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I am using a queue to feed my training examples to my network using the code below, and it works properly.

However, I would like to be able to feed some *testing data* every *n* iterations, but I don't really know how I should proceed. Should I stop momentarily the queue and feed the testing data manually? Should I create another queue just for testing data?

**Edit:** Is the right way of doing it is to create a separate file, say `eval.py`, that continuously reads the last checkpoint and evaluates the network? This is how they do it in the CIFAR10 example.

```
batch = 128 # size of the batch
x = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, n_steps, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float32", [None, n_classes])

queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=4*batch,
                      min_after_dequeue=3*batch,
                      dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.float32],
                      shapes=[[n_steps, n_input], [n_classes]])
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many([x, y])
X_batch, Y_batch = queue.dequeue_many(batch)

sess = tf.Session()

def load_and_enqueue(data):
    while True:
        X, Y = data.get_next_batch(batch)
        sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})

train_thread = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue, args=(data))
train_thread.daemon = True
train_thread.start()

for _ in xrange(max_iter):
    sess.run(train_op)
```

Comment: There are some good high level functions for this that have recently been added to [github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/evaluation.py).  They are based on running evaluations with a separate executable that reads the checkpoint files created by training.

Comment: @user728291, is there any example to do it within the same script? It seems other tools like Caffe just does it like this.

Comment: How about using two queues (or a queue and a placeholder that is fed), and use `tf.where` to decide which of these two sources is used to feed the network?

Answer (score 1):

You can bulid another test Queue and a copy of training model as test model like this:

```
trainX, trainY = Queue0(batchSize, ...)...
testX, testY= Queue1(batchSize, ...)...
modelTrain = inference(trainX, trainY, ...)
# reuse variables
modelTest = inference(testX, testY, ...)
sess.run(train_op,loss_op,trainX,trainY)
sess.run(test_op,testX,testY)
```

This way may consume more memory since 2 models are initialized, hope to see better solution

Answer (score -1):

You can add an eval_op in your codes, and then do evaluation in every n (say n=1000) iterations. An example is as follow:

```
for niter in xrange(max_iter):
    sess.run(train_op)
    if niter % 1000 == 0:
        sess.run(eval_op)
```